# Resource loading in html email

Tags: html, email, html-email

I have been using a dev tools network tab to check out the loading of resources within a HTML email, because sometimes some of the images do not load properly.

Now I am trying to understand if the email client will always execute the html code in a top to bottom approach, or if there are conditions which can change this.

So I have a tracking pixel and it is located at the very bottom of my email.  This pixel does a lot of things which causes it to take about 15 seconds to load.  However, because it is at the bottom of my email, it should not interfere with the images being loaded above it.  That was what I thought all the time until I checked out the Network tab.

Within the email, a lot of the images are dynamically injected. In the network tab, these images normally have a status of 302 - moved temporarily.  It then looks like these images are then reloaded after the tracking pixel has started its request, which could be the cause of some images not loading properly.

I was really hoping for some advice as to whether my theory could be correct, or if I am missing the point altogether?

Thanks

Comment: Im pretty sure that it reads from the top to bottom, like a normal DOM